# Finding row when slashes are added due to apostraphes?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to pull information from a MySQL table using the following query:

```
$skill = mysql_real_escape_string($row['skill']);
$sql = "select * from table where column = '" . $skill . "'
```

However, it can't find it because it adds slashes.  Here's what the original skill is, before mysql_real_escape_string processes it: `Blah blah blah blah blah '`

Here's what it becomes after getting passed through mysql_real_escape_string:

```
Blah blah blah blah blah blah \'
```

My SQL query can't find the particular row it when it looks like that. Is there a way to get MySQL to look for the apostrophe still?

Thanks!!

Comment: The extra backslash will be removed by the SQL parser, so it should all work as intended. Are you sure that row exists? Maybe there is some trailing whitespace?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think it might have to do with the fact that the SQL query is encompassed by single quotes.  Here's the result of the query: `select * from table where column = 'blah blah blah blah \''`

Comment: The row in the DB maybe has real "\" in it, due to incorrect escaping in the insertion query.

Comment: Directly from the DB, the row is: `blah blah blah blah blah blah '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it can't find it because it adds slashes.

**This is wrong assumption.**

It can't find it because of something else.

> Here's what it becomes after getting passed through mysql_real_escape_string: 
>   `Blah blah blah blah blah blah \'`

It's okay, the string is exactly as it should be.

> My SQL query can't find the particular row it when it looks like that.

There is something wrong with either your code or your data. Provide a **full and reproduceable code as well as data**, so we'll be able to help you find a mistake in it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $skill = stripslashes($row['skill']);
    $skill = mysql_real_escape_string($skill);
} else {
    $skill = mysql_real_escape_string($row['skill']);
}

$sql = 'select * from table where column = "' . $skill . '"';
```

EDIT: Sorry, I've just realised that `$row['skill']` probably hasn't come from GET/POST/COOKIE and so `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is probably irrelevant.  Just go straight for the `stripslashes()`:

```
 $skill = stripslashes($row['skill']);
 $skill = mysql_real_escape_string($skill);
 $skill = mysql_real_escape_string($row['skill']);
```

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't seem to be working.  Here's the output of that skill:

`Blah blah blah blah blah blah \'`